# How to update the information without reinstalling the apk?

Tags: android

I have been working on an app that gives information about movies in the cinema. I want to update the information, such as: updating the movies, the description of the movies, inserting new movies, and deleting old movies. I'm not sharing it for the moment on the Play Store, but if I update the information from my xml file I have to reinstall the apk. Do I have to implement a database, or is there another program that will let me update the information?

Comment: You need REST services that your application will consume in order to get content you want to present to users. 
So, you need backend application for that. For playing around you can use www.restservices.org, but for production, you will have to have your backend.

Comment: This site do not work :/

Comment: I just visited it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanna download this content from a server, so you won't need to update the app. Every time the app runs it will download the new information from the server and the changes will be reflected on the app without requiring a reinstallation.

Something you can read: http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html

Comment: What if I don't have a server ?